# How can I change the angle of a line in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, line, matlab-figure, angle

I'm trying to compute two lines, with both having the same value for the first `Y(1)` , but with different lengths. How can I change the angle of the green line, without changing the first `Y(1)` value, in order to have the same inclination as the red one?

[image: lines]

Code:

```
xx4=[-4.07, -43.9450];
yy4=[1.25, 0.46];

xxlais=[37.1225 -35.93];
yylais=[1.25 0.46];

line(xx4,yy4,'Color','r')
hold on
line(xxlais,yylais,'Color','g')
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem on paper?

Comment: You can get the same inclination by changing any of X(1), X(2) or Y(2). Do you have any preference on *how* the angle is changed?

Comment: By changing Y(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First compute the expected slope:

```
slope=(yy4(2)-yy4(1))/(xx4(2)-xx4(1))
```

Then compute the new Y(2):

```
yylais(2)=yylais(1)+slope*(xxlais(2)-xxlais(1))
```